# Nginx Configuration in Kubernetes for Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, nginx, kubernetes

I have deployed rails application in Kubernetes and Currently it is running in 10.x.x.x:8072.I need to implement in https and proxy forward from 10.x.x.x:8072 to url device.application.net. Below the nginx configuration I am using but proxy forward is not happening. Nginx POD is running without any issues. I have created Nginx load balancer service "nginx-service" but I haven't defined this service name in anywhere.Where to define this service name in below configurations. Is there any thing I am missing out?

nginx.conf file

```
upstream docker {
        server 10.x.x.x:8072;
}
        server {
            # define your domain
        server_name device-app.application.net;
                # define the public application root
        listen 80;
        listen 443 ssl;
        ssl_protocols TLSv1.2;
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
        ssl_session_timeout  10m;
        ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:10m;
        ssl_session_tickets off; # Requires nginx >= 1.5.9
        ssl_stapling on; # Requires nginx >= 1.3.7
        ssl_stapling_verify on; # Requires nginx => 1.3.7
        add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=63072000; includeSubDomains; preload";
        add_header X-Frame-Options DENY;
        add_header X-Content-Type-Options nosniff;
        add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";
        ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl_certs/device-app.application.net.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl_certs/device-app.application.net.key;
        proxy_set_header Host device-app.application.net;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
        root   /DEVICEAPP/public;
        index  index.html;
                                             # define where Nginx should write its logs
        access_log /DEVICEAPP/log/nginx.access.log;
        error_log /DEVICEAPP/log/nginx.error.log;
                                            # send non-static file requests to the app server
        location / {
        if ($scheme = 'http') {
        rewrite ^ https://$http_host$request_uri? permanent;
}
        proxy_pass http://docker;
}
}
```

Docker file

```
FROM nginx
# Install dependencies
RUN apt-get update -qq && apt-get -y install apache2-utils
# establish where Nginx should look for files
ENV RAILS_ROOT /DEVICE_APP
# Set our working directory inside the image
WORKDIR $RAILS_ROOT
# create log directory
RUN mkdir log
# copy over static assets
COPY public public/
# Copy Nginx config template
COPY docker/web/nginx.conf /tmp/docker.nginx
# Copy SSL Certs
COPY device-app.application.net.crt /etc/nginx/ssl_certs/device-app.application.net.crt
# Copy private key
COPY device-app.application.net.key /etc/nginx/ssl_certs/device-app.application.net.key
# substitute variable references in the Nginx config template for real values from the environment
# put the final config in its place
RUN envsubst '$RAILS_ROOT' < /tmp/docker.nginx > /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
```

Nginx Load balancer

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  namespace: device-app
  name: nginx-service
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 80
      name: http
      targetPort: 80
  selector:
    app: device-app-nginx
```

Comment: How is your kubernetes cluster is deployed? On-prem or cloud?

Comment: Deployed in cloud

Comment: Could you please also provide which cluster version you have? How is it set up? (e.g. AKS or GKE or `kubeadm` on VMs). Pod's yaml? How is connection established and from where? Ideally is to see a response from your application from another pod with `curl`.

Comment: Could you please describe the desired request-response path and add example of such request using `curl`, describing where `curl` is running, expected and actual response. It might help if you increase logs verbosity and add some logs messages that relevant to that `curl` request. https://www.papertrail.com/solution/tips/logging-with-nginx-how-to-configure-it-and-what-to-watch-out-for/